# Adding a security group to AD user account using PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2016, security-groups

I am trying to build a PowerShell command that it will add a security group (not on Member Of) with full control permissions in AD user in order avoid doing it manually by hand. Is it possible ?

[This is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ7Up.png)

Comment: try doing a search for `learn powershell by using ADAC`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I figured out the command using dsacls:

```
dsacls "CN=UserCN,OU=UserOU,OU=UserOU,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=domain" /I:T /g "\MSOL_code:GA"
```